# Node.JS Shutdown Hook

Tags: node.js, solaris, kill, sigterm, shutdown-hook

Is it possible to intercept the default `kill` signal and use it as a command for a graceful shutdown? This is for Solaris SMF. The easiest way to have a stoppable service that I have found is to set `:kill` as the shutdown script and then to add a shutdown hook in Java. In this case, I want to do it for Node.JS. How should I do it?

Edit: The purpose is to

1. Stop receiving new requests.
2. Give existing callbacks a few seconds to finish.
3. Write some information to stderr.

@alienhard's first suggestion was to use `process.on('exit'...` but it seems that I would not be able to accomplish number 2 with this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is using signal events.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/process.html#signal_Events

Answer (score 14):

There is an `exit` event: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/process.html#event_exit_

```
process.on('exit', function() {
  console.log('About to exit.');
});
```

**Edit:** An alternative that could work for you, is instead of killing the process, sending a signal like SIGUSR1 (`kill -s SIGUSR1`), and then listening for this signal (see link posted by @masylum in another answer) and after you are done or some time has elapsed explicitly terminate with process.exit().

Comment: It the docs say *"The main event loop will no longer be run after the 'exit' callback finishes, so timers may not be scheduled."*. If I understand correctly, I will not be able to use `setTimeout` or other events or callbacks. Is that correct? If that is correct, I would like instead to have a callback where I can delay the exit by several seconds and allow other callbacks to finish. Is there such a thing?

Comment: This didn't work on windows. Should I even be trying it on anything but *nix? ;-)